# Newton's Method for Two Equations

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

Problem:

Find the zeros of the following system of equations using Newton's method.
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x,y) &=& x^2 + y^2 - 3 \\
g(x,y) &=& 3x^2 + y^3 - 6 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer:

I am using the following web page as a source for Newton's method.

www.math.ohiou.edu/courses/math3600/lecture13.pdf

The following plot shows that there is at least one solution.
[Graph][http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+-+3+%3D+0+,+3*x%5E2+%2B+y%5E3+-+6+%3D+0]

Note: This Plot only shows one equation which is less than ideal.

First, I find the partial derivatives.
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_x &=& 2x \\
f_y &=& 2y \\
g_x &=& 6x \\
g_y &=& 3y^2 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
My initial guess with be $x_0 = [1,1]$. Note that $x_0$ is a vector
with two components $(x,y)$. Now, I apply the formula:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_1 &=& x_0 - (Df(x_0))^{-1} f(x_0) \\
Df(x_0) &=&
\begin{bmatrix}
f_x(1,1) & f_y(1,1) \\
g_x(1,1) & g_y(1,1) \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
Df(x_0) &=&
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
6 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, I have a problem. This matrix is not invertible. Did I do something
wrong? Is there a reason why this method would not work correctly in this case?
Bob

Correction: After fixing my error, I get an invertible matrix. Thank you.

Comment: @ Moo - I made a mistake. Thanks for the response. I need to fix my post. Bob.

Comment: I updated my post and I still have a problem. Bob

Comment: Write the general solution for $\delta x$ and $\delta y$. That will give you a hint about the allowed 'starting points'.

Comment: @ Felix Marin - Thanks for the response. I do not understand what you mean by $\delta x$ and $\delta y$. Also, I am thinking all starting points on the interval should be valid. Is that a bad assumption?

Comment: @Moo I have no idea why $g_x = 6x$ for the new equation.

Comment: @Moo - You are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your partial derivatives as $g_x = 6x$ in which case the Jacobian at $x_0 = [1,1]$ is not singular and converges to $x = [1.0885, 1.3473]$. Otherwise, singular Jacobians typically arise from a bad initial starting point. There is a modified Newton's method which can handle this, see Hueso, J. L., et al., Modified Newton's method for systems of nonlinear equations with singular Jacobian.